# How can I indent multiple lines, and indent "backwards", in gvim?

Tags: vim, editing, gvim

I'm just learning vim (via gvim, I used to be a Notepad++ user) and haven't yet found how to do 2 things:

1. How can I indent a set of rows x spaces/tabs right? In Notepad++, for example, I just highlight the rows I need and press 'Tab' key.
2. Also, is there a way to move backwards equivalent to "Shift+Tab" in Notepad++?

Thanks

Comment: As Luc Hermitte suggested, vimers use the 'indent' or 'indentation' keyword in this context. By tabs we mean something slightly different - a layout feature. For more help, see **:help tabpage** in vim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start at the first line you want to indent, then press > and type the number of lines you want to indent and press > again (for 10 lines you'd press >10>)  To un-indent you'd just use < instead of >  (<10<)

Comment: Yes, that worked. Any way of doing that without first knowing how many lines I'd want to indent? Is there a way to select all the lines I want using the cursor and then issuing the command?

Comment: I don't know about selecting lines, but you can use >> to indent just the current line, then use the 'repeat last command' key (.) on all subsequent lines ([down][.][down][.][down][.]) After a while you get quite fast at this ;)

Comment: @drapkin11: One way to select the lines you want to shift is to move the cursor to the first line, type `V`, then move the cursor to the last line. All the selected lines should be highlighted. Now type `<` to shift the selected lines left or `>` to shift right.

Comment: @garyjohn, your suggestion works very well

Answer (score 3):

What you want are the > and < commands, see "`:help shift-left-right`".

You can use these commands in multiple ways, but since you specifically mentioned highlighting, you can just use your mouse or keyboard to highlight the lines you want to shift/unshift and press > or <.

Instead of using visual mode (highlight) you can provide a count and >> or <<.  For example, `3>>` will indent the current line and two lines below it.

Comment: Right, I did as you suggested in your 2nd statement, but for some reason when I press '<', my selected rows are just overwritten with the '<' character! Certainly not what I intend.

Comment: It looks like you have mswin.vim sourced, which makes some things in Vim behave more like "standard" Windows editing dialogs/notepad.

Comment: @drapkin11, I believe @Heptite is correct about mswin. If you use V when highlighting rows you will not have this problem.

Comment: @johnny, you are correct, the issue goes away. @garyjohn suggested the same solution which works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred approach is to let vim perform auto-indentation.
Don't forget this in your .vimrc:

```
set ai
filetype indent on
```

Then, if you open a file badly indented, you can then use the `=` command (in conjunction with a motion, e.g. `gg=G` to reindent the whole file, `==` to reindent the current line, `=i{` to reindent the current `{}` block, etc.).

`>>` and `<<` exist indeed, since the old and plain vi, but they are really cumbersome for  real and long term editing.