# How to indent and reverse indent text with "Tab" and "Shift+Tab"?

Tags: vim

I'm getting started with vim for markdown.

```
* Level 1 text
* On pressing enter it comes here
*     On pressing tab it comes here
```

What I want is, I want to modify (increase or decrease) the level of bullet point using keys. (In other text editors, `Tab` increases the intent level and `Shift+Tab` decreases it)

```
* Level 1 bullet. On pressing Enter,
* It comes here. On pressing Enter and then Tab,
    * I want it to come here. To go to the previous level, on pressing Enter and then Enter/Shift+Tab,
* I want it to come here.
```

This was the behaviour in VS Code.

Upon searching I added `set ai` and `filetype indent on` to my empty `.vimrc` (Just installed Vundle as in the instructions) but I was not successful.

How can I get this work done?

Possible duplicate: [How can I indent multiple lines, and indent "backwards", in gvim?](https://superuser.com/questions/251989/how-can-i-indent-multiple-lines-and-indent-backwards-in-gvim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out this Vim plugin which does the expected behaviour for markdown files.

Here is a link to the same: [gabrielelana](https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown)

Answer (score 6):

Vim has a different philosophy.

In normal mode, press `>` twice to add indentation and `<` twice to remove.
To do this for multiple lines, enter visual mode with `v` and select the lines, then press `>` or `<` twice.

In insert mode, you can press `ctrl-d` to remove indentation.

`set ai` doesn't work here because vim can't guess what indentation you want in markdown in comparison to code.

Comment: Hey just found this plugin that could do the same... https://github.com/gabrielelana/vim-markdown

Comment: Might be more clear to say that it's the `<` or `>` key (accessed with SHIFT on my keyboard) since there's no `>>` key.